# Mule 4 : Batch Processing and Streaming : How to process million plus records without java memory heap issues?

Tags: mule4

Scenario :
Assuming a CSV file containing 1 million records.
Using Mule 4 Batch processing to process this file, but we don't want to read the entire file in memory as it will give us **Out of memory** issue.
So we want to use the Streaming capability of File connector.

Tried methods:

- Creating a Java class and using InputBufferStream to split the incoming file in new csv files having 1000 records each
- Storing these new smaller files in another folder, Polling this folder and reading these smaller csv files
- Processing the smaller files in Batch.
- After completed processing, deleting the smaller files.

Help Needed :
How can we use **Mule 4 CSV file streaming** concept to skip the Java file splitting?

Comment: why are you generating new CSV files instead of working directly with the original file? Have you tried it and got the out of memory error? Do yo know what was the top consumer of memory? What kind of transformation and process is done in the batch?

Comment: @aled The file size is 500 MB and reading the entire file using File connector gives MULE STACK OVERFLOW ERROR. So I am splitting the files, But as mentioned, I want to understand how can we directly work with the original file with streaming capability. The transformations include mapping to a new object structure and then filtering and sending out emails for the final selected records.

Comment: A stack overflow error is not the same as an out of memory. Please share details of the error (error message, stack trace), and File connector and Mule version.